# retrieve column dynamically from json data

Tags: jquery

I have an array of columns:

```
var columns=["title","length","status"];
```

Here is my code:

```
    function executeSearch(query)
    {                       
        var url = ajaxPath+ "?s=search&r="+resource+"&q="+query;
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){          
            var html = '<table class="table table-hover">';
            html += '<thead><tr>';
            $(columns).each(function(index,value){
                html +='<td>'+value+'</td>';
            })
            html += '</tr></thead>';
            html += '<tbody>';          
            $(data).each(function(i,item){
                html += '<tr>';
                $(item).each(function(e,itm){
                    for(var propt in itm){
                        if (columns.hasOwnProperty(propt)) {
                            html += '<td>'+itm[propt]+'</td>';
                        }
                    }                   
                })
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            html += '</tbody>';
            html += '</table>';
            $("#datatable").html(html);
        });
    }
```

I'm trying to get the data based on the columns. I'm using `columns.hasOwnProperty`.

It doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Is there a `jquery` method for handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`columns` in your example is an array, you should use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to figure out if the column is in the array.

```
// check if the propt is in the array (-1 means not found)
if (coulmns.indexOf(propt) !== -1) {
```

However, in the case you are looking at you should probably be iterating over the `columns` array instead of the `items` property.  You are building a table, and you want the columns to be in the order you specified...

Instead of `$(item).each()` you should `$.each(columns, function(index, propt) {` and build your table using `item[propt]`

Comment: Thanks. This worked, however I think i need to iterate over each tr item and apply the columns to each td. Regardless, it worked fine. thanks